# Alternative parametrizations of linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, parametrization

Matrices seem to be the most common parametrization of linear transformations with the geometrical meaning of columns of the matrix being the re-mapped basis vectors. But sometimes it's difficult to visualize what exact effect will a linear transform (represented by a matrix) have on, let's say, the unit circle.

For example, I see eigenvectors and eigenvalues as an alternative parametrization of linear transformations, because they tell in which directions and by how much does a linear transformation stretch space, although some linear transformations have complex eigenvectors and eigenvalues, which breaks this stretching analogy for me. Another flaw in this analogy for me is that I fail to see why e.g. $2\times 2$ matrices cannot encode more than 2 axes of stretching (more than 2 eigenvectors).

When playing with 2D basis vectors, I saw that shear transforms produce results similar to camera movement in 3D space. Maybe N-dimensional transforms can be also expressed as certain operations on (N+1)-dimensional space?

Are there any other useful parametrizations of linear transformations that could perhaps bring more intuitive insight into how non-trivial (non-orthogonal) linear transformations affect space?

Comment: It is not exactly what you are asking for, but in the early XX century [cracovians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracovian) were sometimes used instead of matrices, for computational purposes.

And for something closer to your interests, take a look at [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Eigenvalues alone might not be useful for thinking about linear transformations geometrically (non-diagonalizable transformations form one class of annoying cases), but singular values are better in achieving this goal.

Comment: In fact, using SVD you can write any linear transformation you like as a product of orthogonal and diagonal matrices (which are those you are mentioning in your post as having clear geometric meaning).

Comment: @radekzak thank you for mentioning cracovians, this is the first time I heard about them.